# embed file in Excel cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, embedded

I'm working on a simple "DB" for some people at work and I don't want to do anything fancy.

the fields should be something like

name , number , notes , File:resume, notes

(where file:notes is the acutall embedded resume. I cant see any obvious way to do this but i thought i would ask just the same.

Is there a way to take a (pdf , doc , docx , txt) and throw it into a cell so a user can click on it and it will open the file in the approate program

note: this db is going to be floating around between multiple sites so linking won't work.

Answer (score 3):

In the Excel Ribbon, head for the menu **`Insert -> Object`**. Select **`Create from file`** and browse to find your file (PDF, DOCX, TXT, etc.). You have even the option to have it shown as an icon or content.